# Create table for razor checkboxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, styling

Currently, I have a set of checkboxes for the months in a year I have created in Razor. I would like to change the checkboxes and make it look like a calendar (using javascript) where the user can select month and the month will be highlighted. Below is the razor syntax I have created:

```
<center>
        <div class="col-2 Border CheckboxMonthStyle" id="checkboxMonthGrid">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                    <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the month(s) the task should be set at</h4>
                </li>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Schedule.MonthInfo.Count; i++)
                {
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                        <div class="checkbox-inline" id="checkboxMonth">
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Schedule.MonthInfo[i].monthID)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Schedule.MonthInfo[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkboxMonth", data_test = Model.Schedule.MonthInfo[i].NofD })
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Schedule.MonthInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.Schedule.MonthInfo[i].monthName)
                        </div>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
                @Html.CheckBox("checkAll", false, new { @id = "checkAllMonths", @onclick = "toggleMonth(this);" })
                @Html.Label("Select All")
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
```

Here is the JS I have made so far. I have managed to create a table with 3 columns and 4 rows but I dont know how to populate the cells with the checkboxes.

```
<script>

//looping through list of checkboxes in months
        var test = document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxMonth');
        for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            console.log(test[i]);
        }

        var colcount = 3;
        var rowcount = 4;

        document.write("<table border=1>")
        for (row = 1; row <= rowcount; row++) {
            document.write("<tr>")
            for (col = 1; col <= colcount; col++) {



                document.write("<td>" + row + "<br>C" + col + "</td>")
            }
            document.write("</tr>")
        }
        document.write("</table>")


    </script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason the Datepicker() from JQuery wont work for your needs?

Comment: I've taken a look at DatePicker. Unfortunately, my months, days of months and days of weeks cannot be linked to each other. I'm taking each value from user selection and doing different things with them.

Comment: OK, NP, It appeared you may have been trying to reinvent that was why i asked.